# В Unity есть отрисованный при помощи Tilemap и Tile Palette уровень. Как повесить коллайдеры на весь уровень? Не подойдет Tilemap collider

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

Не подходит стандартный коллайдер для Tilemap, поскольку поверхность земли находится не на краю тайла, а чуть ниже, на нарисованной на тайле земле, и, соответвственно, сам коллайдер тоже нужно сдвинуть чуть ниже. Коротко говоря, как повесить коллайдер на уровень из вот таких тайлов: 
[image: верхняя полоса - земля]

Comment: по моему есть Polygon Collider или что-то такое, где сам вырисовываешь свой коллайдер, ставя точки

Comment: Спасибо) не знал о таком. А то пока что просто поднял коллайдер всех персонажей, чтобы они ниже ходили)